# How to find if objects intersect if I know bounding Sphere of each object

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

I need to find if objects (`count = 15`) intersect. I know radius of bounding Sphere and center coordinates (`x,y,z`) of each object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.boundingSphere` is an object of `THREE.Sphere()`.

If you read documentation attentively, then you'll find that that object has [`.intersectsSphere()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Sphere.intersectsSphere.intersectsSphere) method, which returns a boolean value.
So, when you add a new object, then compute its bounding sphere and check, if it intersects with the bounding sphere of any of previous objects.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over every object1 and over every object2. Use the Pythagorean theorem twice to figure out the (3d) distance between object1 and object2, then check to see if the distance is greater than either of their radiuses.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to only test bounding spheres, then CertainPerformance's answer is correct.  Given P1 = (x1,y1,z1) and P2 = (x2,y2,z2), the distance between P1 and P2 is given by d(P1,P2) = (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2

If you want to check a convex hull it can still be done fairly easily, but if your object is concave, you have to look at the "triangle soup" to check for collisions and it's REALLY going to be slow (think seconds instead of a few milliseconds).  An alternative is to decompose the concave model into multiple convex models and do a convex hull collision test.  (see here: https://github.com/kmammou/v-hacd)

Here's another good reference for collision detection in general: https://www.toptal.com/game/video-game-physics-part-ii-collision-detection-for-solid-objects

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of spheres that got a position (x, y, z)  and a radius (r) its as simple as:

```
 function getSphereIntersect(array){
  for(const [i, spere1] of array.entries()) {
    for(const sphere2 of array.slice(i + 1)){
      const distance = Math.sqrt(
        (sphere1.x - sphere2.x) ** 2 +
        (sphere1.y - shere2.y) ** 2 +
        (sphere1.z - sphere2.z) ** 2
     );
    if(distance < sphere1.r + sphere2.r)
     return [sphere1, sphere2];
  }
 }
}
```

or if sphere1 got a position that implements a Vector, its even more to check for an intersection:

```
  sphere1.pos.sub(shpere2.pos).len() < sphere1.r + sphere2.r
```